# How to change text in button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML Code is like this :

```
<table>
  <tbody class="iteration">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="save">More</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cruisedropd">
          <div class="loading"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="iteration">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="save">More</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cruisedropd">
          <div class="loading"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My Javascript code is like this :

```
$(function(){
    $(".cruisedropd").hide();
    $('.save').click(function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest("tbody.iteration");

        parent.toggleClass('is_loading',  parent.hasClass('is_loading') );
        parent.find(".cruisedropd").toggle();
        parent.find('.loading').html("work");

    });


});
```

Demo is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/53okmr78/1/

I want to change text in button. So when click button "more", the button change to button "hide". Vice versa

Thank you very much

Comment: I update my question and jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y75eL9m9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

> A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

```
$('.save').click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(_, text) {
      return text == "More" ? "Hide" : "More";
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y75eL9m9/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your function

```
    $(function(){
    $(".cruisedropd").hide();
    $('.save').click(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.text() == "More" ? $self.text('Hide') : $self.text('More');

        var parent = $(this).closest("tbody.iteration");
        $(parent).block({ message: null }); 

        parent.toggleClass('is_loading',  parent.hasClass('is_loading') );
        parent.find(".cruisedropd").toggle();
        parent.find('.loading').html("work");

    });


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/53okmr78/6/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `$(".save").click(){...`

```
if($(this).text() == "More"){
    $(this).text("Hide");
}else{
    $(this).text("More")
}
```